# Integrate SWIG generated scripts on Ubuntu

Tags: python, swig

I have a couple of files that I need to integrate on ubuntu and run a python script using them:

- file.py
- _file.pyd
- first.dll
- second.dll

From my understanding the py and pyd file were generated using SWIG. 
My question is how can I use them on an Ubuntu machine (if that is even possible from the start).

Thanks

Comment: I tried copying the files to the site-packages folder, but when trying to do an import of the module in the python console I get an error that the module was not found. I didn't mention this in the question as I am not from a python background and wasn't sure if its relevant

Comment: `first.dll` and `second.dll` - sounds like these are Windows DLLs rather than Linux shared objects. You need a Linux build of this library to run it on Ubuntu.

Comment: all files are generated from a windows environment. in this case, without building them for linux, there's no way of running them? is the wine tool a good idea in this case?

Comment: Life will be easier if you can get a Linux build :-). If you use WINE you'll need to install a Windows Python (of the right version for your pyd) and run your python script with that. You may have problems getting Python to install - http://askubuntu.com/questions/330141/install-python-in-wine may help.

Comment: yeah i thought so, problem is i have no control over it at this point.